# Leontief inverse in undirected network

Tags: matrices, economics, network

I sort of understand how the Leontief inverse is measured and where it is used. Though it occurred to me whether it makes sense to use this approach in undirected networks (e.g. correlation matrix).

Comment: How about giving some more details about your question, such as a brief explanation of what you mean by Leontief inverse for non experts?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139801/understanding-the-leontief-inverse this is a good overview of what it is. @Ruy