# Closed form for summation of matrix multiplication by its transpose

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Assume $A_{N\times{N}}$ is a square matrix. Is there a closed form for $$I+A+AA'+(AA')A'+((AA')A')A'+...$$
Essentially a closed form for multiplication of the matrix by its transpose for infinite times. If yes, then are there any conditions that need to be satisfied?

PS: This occurred to me since we have the Leontief inverse ([Understanding the Leontief inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139801/understanding-the-leontief-inverse)) as $(I-A)^{-1}=I+A+A^2+A^3+...$ so thought there might be something similar to this notion with the transpose.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is associative, so this is $I + A + AA^T +A A^{T2} + AA^{T3} + ...$

Comment: Using that so-called _Leontif inverse_  the sum is $\;I+A(I-A^T)^{-1}\;$

Comment: Let $B$ be that matrix $A'$ for an easy typing. Note that you can get rid of the many parentheses in the expression, e.g. $(AB)B$ is simply $ABB=AB^2$. Then you want to compute:$$I+A\underbrace{(I+B+B^2+B^3+\dots)}_{(I-B)^{-1}}\ ,$$ and the series of $B$-powers converges if $B$ is has (some) multiplicative norm $<1$, "same series"   as in the question for $A$.